# Cassandra Light Weight Queries

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am using cassandra weight light queries - specifically inserts. In some cases, the insert is successful, however the query returns a false. I am unable to isolate this behavior to identify cause.

I am with a 5 node Cassandra cluster - 2.2.7. The key space I am operating on has a replication factor - 1

I am using java cassandra connector like below

`Cluster.builder().addContactPoints("<cassandraip>")
        .withProtocolVersion(ProtocolVersion.V3)
        .build();`

Has anyone encountered this behavior before?

Comment: What's 'light queries'? Do you mean 'lightweight transaction' or that you're running a light reading/inserting load?

Comment: typo ... I meant light weight queries.